# Access data in a JSON file locally in browser without a separate network call

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Suppose we have a JSON file with static data for our Angular 5 app. We want to "embed" it in app scripts, so when we'd like to get data from it, the app will not make a round trip to server for it.

Can you explain how to achieve it from configuring the Angular CLI (if needed) up to the TypeScript code returning data from that JSON file?

Comment: Maybe json server can do it, check it here: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Not sure if I understand exactly what you want to do but if you just wanty to load JSON data like some data stored in variable, you can parse it and assign to variable instead of holding it in separate file ``export const data = JSON.parse(` paste your JSON here`)``

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik: Yes, I want to simply load contents of JSON to a variable. The reason for that is because that JSON is created by some tool as a part of build process. So I'm wondering if the task of loading a JSON file is something ordinary in Angular world before changing the tool/build process.

Comment: This isn't unusual. As long as the JSON is in the assets folder it will be delivered to the client at a part of the application. You can read the contents of the file using HttpClient, and use data any way you would like.

Comment: @R.Richards: Sure, but the question is how to do it without a separate HTTP call to server.

Comment: This isn't a call to a server. This is just using the HttpClient to pick up the content of a bundled file. There is no http://... in the path to the file, the file is in the assets folder... at the client... delivered with all the other parts of the application. See?

Comment: @R.Richards: Can you explain how it works? If we put something into `assets`, it's not getting bundled into app scripts, it would be left in `assets` folder on web server, right? This means that you still need an extra server request to get every file from `assets` sooner or later. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the json file as though it is a url endpoint in your service.

If you have say a file called `foo.json` in `assets/foo.json` you simply embed that path to your http call.

```
//this is in src/ directory which is one layer deep from assets
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('../assets/foo.json');
  }
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely true, but the question is how to get it without an extra service call. Basically, I'm looking for a way to make it a part of app bundle.

Comment: A service will be bundled with your app and it’s not making a real network call anyway...

Comment: It's interesting! Sorry, didn't know about it. I've made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json), but it doesn't hit `subscribe()` method of the `http.get()`. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: It's not gonna work on stackblitz, make the `../assets/foo.json` to `assets/foo.json` and it should work locally

Comment: It doesn't work locally without making a network call to server for `foo.json`. Try to set breakpoint on `this.http.get()`, then shut down your web server and clear browser cache - it never gets into `subscribe()` of that call.